# Threads - ¿Por qué tener más hilos es mejor?

Tags: java, hilos

Sé que no hay que tener una cantidad exagerada de hilos porque el hardware colapsa, no da para tanto. Pero al ver estas imágenes me surgió una duda...

[image: Img1]

[image: Img2]

¿Por qué al dividir los procesos tarda menos?¿Será que así uso mas núcleos en vez de uno y no sólo uno para correr el thread principal?

¿Tengo razón o estoy equivocado?

Comment: Hola, también depende del problema a resolver, existen problemas que no es conveniente utilizar hilos. Y utilizando hilos en java logras concurrencia, no paralelismo, eso es otro punto a tener en cuenta que mucha gente confunde. Por otro lado, el concepto de proceso no es el mismo que el concepto de hilos. Saludos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ¿Porque al dividir los procesos tarda menos?

Claro que tienes razón, A grandes rasgos, obviamente tardara más si tus procesos se ejecutan secuencialmente que si se realizaran todos en paralelo (Concurrencia). Si se realizan en paralelo tu sistema tendría más eficiencia a la hora de ejecutarse.

Esto lo comento suponiendo que tus procesos son candidatos a ejecutarse en un thread, como una tarea asincrona, debes tener cuidado porque existen procesos o tareas que podrían provocar problemas al ser ejecutadas en Threads.

> ¿Será que así uso mas nucleos en vez de uno y no solo uno para correr
>   el thread principal?

Exactamente al ejecutar más tareas estas son distribuidas (dependiendo del hardware y el SO)  para su procesamiento en los nucleos.

Existen algunas propiedades de los hilos que sería interesante revisaras:

- Prioridad.
  Para determinar que hilo debe ejecutarse primero, ya que cada hilo posee su propia prioridad.
- Sincronización.
  Si es invocado un método `synchronized`, únicamente el hilo que lo invoca tiene acceso a la instancia del Objeto, cualquier otro hilo que intente accesar esta misma instancia tendrá que esperar.
- Agrupamiento.
  Ver clase `ThreadGroup`, implementa los grupos de hilos en Java.

Comment: No solo depende del hardware. En caso de Java, depende del sistema operativo.

Comment: Pero si yo tengo un núcleo, él lo mismo que nada no? Digo, separar los hilos sería lo mismo que nada, ya que ocuparía el mismo carril(núcleo) solo que alternándose.

Comment: Yo digo las cosas media afirmándolas así me aseguró que tengo razón y no pienso que las tengo la razón cuando no.

Comment: Si tienes un núcleo, podría llegar a ser lo mismo que nada? Actualmente las pc o dispositivos móviles cuentan regularmente con más de un solo núcleo. Es importante evaluar cuando en verdad necesitas usar Hilos, ya que teniendo un solo núcleo en algunos casos podría ser un problema como crear varios hilos.

Comment: Lo que dice Elenasys sobre la sincronización es falso. Cualquier hilo puede acceder a la instancia de un Objeto en que se haya hecho llamado a un método synchronized. [Demostración](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40841/si-es-invocado-un-m%C3%A9todo-synchronized-%C3%BAnicamente-el-hilo-que-lo-invoca-tiene-a?noredirect=1#comment70159_40841)

Comment: (づ◔ ͜ʖ◔)づ te recomiendo veas syncronized de la documentación oficial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.

Comment: Es cierto que dos invocaciones de un método sincronizado de un objeto no pueden intercalarse, y yo nunca he dicho lo contrario. Sigue siendo falso esto:"Si es invocado un método synchronized, únicamente el hilo que lo invoca tiene acceso a la instancia del Objeto, cualquier otro hilo que intente accesar esta misma instancia tendrá que esperar." Puesto que la invocación de métodos sincronizados no es la única forma de acceder a una instancia y la sincronización de java no te protege contra estas otras formas de acceso.

Answer (score 10):

Del título:

> ¿Por qué tener más hilos es mejor?

La idea de hilos es tener trabajo realizándose al mismo tiempo. Un ejemplo para esto es: imagina que tienes que pintar una habitación de cuatro paredes. Si solo tienes un pintor que pinta 1 pared a 1 hora, para pintar la habitación se demorará 4 horas. Si necesitas agilizar este trabajo, contratas a un pintor más y la habitación estará pintada en 2 horas, pero deberás pagar al pintor extra. Lo mismo sucede con los hilos: puedes obtener más velocidad pero pagarás un precio extra por obtener esa velocidad, en este caso es pagar el procesamiento extra por tener dos (o más) procesos ejecutándose al mismo tiempo. Para los tiempos actuales con computadoras y dispositivos de al menos dos núcleos en el micro procesador, esto no es tanto un problema. Pero ten en cuenta que hay procesos que no se pueden optimizar utilizando hilos. Un ejemplo en la vida real sería el embarazo de una mujer: no importa cuántas enfermeras (hilos) pongas para que ayuden a la mujer embarazada, el proceso demorará lo que deba demorar (entre 7 y 9 meses).

Del texto:

> ¿Porque al dividir los procesos tarda menos?

De la respuesta anterior, depende del tipo de proceso. Hay cosas que no se pueden optimizar con hilos, por ejemplo acceso a disco o acceso a través de la red, esos son procesos lentos. Sin embargo, hay procesos que sí se pueden optimizar usando hilos, como por ejemplo la generación de facturas para un grupo de clientes: puedes tener un método `generaFactura(long idCliente)`, tener un pool de hilos y mandar tareas al pool para que la generación de facturas sea en paralelo (similar al de pintar las paredes de una habitación).

Esto en código se representaría de la siguiente manera, utilizando [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (porque es mejor usar un framework que maneje los hilos en lugar de tener que manejarlos manualmente):

```
public void generaFactura(long idCliente) {
    //proceso para generar la factura...
}

//...

//en algún método
List<Long> listaIdClientes = obtenerIdClientesPorFacturar();
//Iniciando pool de hilos
int cantidadHilos = ... ; //cantidad de hilos en el pool
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cantidadHilos);
//dejando tareas en el pool de hilos
for (final Long idCliente : listaIdClientes) {
    executor.execute( () -> generaFactura(idCliente) );
}
//dejar de admitir tareas en el pool de hilos
executor.shutdown();
//el código de acá abajo es opcional
//indica que se debe esperar a que todas las tareas en el
//pool de hilos deben terminar su ejecución
//y que el hilo en ejecución esperará esto
while (!executor.isTerminated() ) { }
```

> ¿Será que así uso mas núcleos en vez de uno y no solo uno para correr el thread principal?

En el caso de Java, esto depende. Cuando abres un hilo, lo que hace Java es delegar la operación al sistema operativo. Así que el uso de uno o más núcleos en este caso va a depender del sistema operativo y no de Java. Esto significa que tu aplicación escrita en Java que utiliza N hilos en Linux puede rendir mejor (o quizás peor) que al ejecutarla en Windows. Asimismo, la ejecución de los hilos está asociada al hardware como mencionaste. Por ende, aunque tengas el mismo sistema operativo p.e. CentOS 6.5 (una distribución de linux) puede rendir diferente entre computadoras debido al hardware que tengan: cantidad de núcleos, caché, ram, etc.

Tal como se muestra en el ejemplo de código más arriba, la cantidad de hilos a utilizar debe depender de realizar pruebas ([benchmark](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(inform%C3%A1tica))) sobre la tarea que se está haciendo y elegir cuál sería el mejor valor pensando en el ambiente o ambientes que se ejecutarán. No hay una fórmula o cálculo perfecto para ello.

Adicional a esto, puedes abrir un hilo o más dentro de otros hilos. Un ejemplo de esto es cuando creas una aplicación web. Cada petición hecha al servidor se realiza dentro de un hilo, y si dentro del proceso de petición abres un hilo, entonces estás abriendo un hilo dentro de otro hilo. Esto no es ningún problema, es totalmente soportado por los sistemas operativos actuales.

En resumen: solo utiliza hilos si realmente lo necesitas. Y recuerda siempre hacer un benchmark de tu proceso antes de utilizar hilos y luego de utilizar hilos para que evalúes si el costo pagado por el uso de hilos vale a comparación del tiempo ganado.