# Si es invocado un método synchronized, ¿únicamente el hilo que lo invoca tiene acceso a la instancia del Objeto?

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo una instancia de un Objeto y llamo a un método `synchronized` de esa instancia desde un hilo.

Mientras se está ejecutando ese método, ¿pueden otros hilos acceder a esa misma instancia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La respuesta sencilla y directa es que, ejecutar un método `synchronized` no es en sí una garantía que otros hilos no puedan acceder a miembros o ejecutar métodos del objeto.

#### Explicación más detallada

Garantías al ejecutar un método `synchronized`:

- Mientras se ejecute un método `synchronized` *de instancia* llamado `M`, ningún otro hilo puede ejecutar:

  1. código que esté "protegido" por un bloque `synchronized(obj) { ... }` <sup>[1]</sup> donde `obj` es una referencia a la misma instancia a la que pertenece el método `M`.
  2. el mismo método `M` o cualquier otro método `synchronized` de instancia que pertenezca a la misma instancia.
- Mientras se ejecute un método `synchronized` *de clase o estático* llamado `M`, ningún otro hilo puede ejecutar:

  1. código que esté "protegido" por un bloque `synchronized(A.class) { ... }` <sup>[1]</sup> donde `A` es la clase que define el método `M`.
  2. el mismo método `M` o cualquier otro método `synchronized` de clase o estático que pertenezca a la misma clase `A`.

O, generalizando lo antedicho, mientras ejecutes algún código "protegido" por un bloque `synchronized(obj1) { ... }` <sup>[1]</sup> <sup>[2]</sup>, ningún otro hilo puede ejecutar el mismo código o cualquier otro código protegido por un bloque `synchronized(obj2) { ... }` <sup>[2]</sup> donde `obj1` y `obj2` son referencias al mismo objeto.

Volviendo a la pregunta, esto signfica que mientras estés ejecutando un método `synchronized` para una instancia `x`, no hay nada que impida que otros hilos accedan a miembros o ejecuten métodos de `x` que no estén protegidos por un bloque `synchronized(x)`  <sup>[1]</sup> <sup>[2]</sup>.

#### Demostraciones

Por ejemplo, aquí tenemos un código con 2 hilos que ambos tratan de ejecutar simultáneamente métodos `synchronized` distintos de una misma instancia:

```
class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Compartido compartido = new Compartido();
        new Thread(() -> compartido.m1()).start();
        Thread.sleep(10);
        new Thread(() -> compartido.m2()).start();
    }

    private static class Compartido {
        public synchronized void m1() {
            logLlamada("m1");
        }

        public synchronized void m2() {
            logLlamada("m2");
        }

        private void logLlamada(String methodName) {
            System.out.printf("%s - entrada%n", methodName);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.printf("%s - salida%n", methodName);
        }
    }
}
```

Debido a que los 2 métodos `m1` y `m2` están `synchronized` y son de la misma instancia, el segundo hilo espera que la ejecución de `m1` termine antes de ejecutar `m2`, como lo demuestra el resultado:

```
m1 - entrada
m1 - salida
m2 - entrada
m2 - salida
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/AIVC91242)</kbd>

En contraste, si modificamos el código y le quitamos el modificador `synchronized` al método `m2`:

```
class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Compartido compartido = new Compartido();
        new Thread(() -> compartido.m1()).start();
        Thread.sleep(10);
        new Thread(() -> compartido.m2()).start();
    }

    private static class Compartido {
        public synchronized void m1() {
            logLlamada("m1");
        }

        public void m2() { // no synchronized
            logLlamada("m2");
        }

        private void logLlamada(String methodName) {
            System.out.printf("%s - entrada%n", methodName);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.printf("%s - salida%n", methodName);
        }
    }
}
```

... entonces notamos que, aunque `m1` es synchronized, esto no impide que el segundo hilo pueda ejecutar `m2` simultáneamente, como lo demuestra el resultado:

```
m1 - entrada
m2 - entrada
m1 - salida
m2 - salida
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/EEED25398)</kbd>

---

<sub>[1] Cuando uso la expresión *código "protegido" por un bloque `synchronized(obj) { ... }`*, me refiero a que el código lógicamente (en la pila de llamadas) queda dentro del bloque `synchronized(obj) { ... }` al momento de *ejecutarse*.</sub>

<sub>[2] Un método `synchronized` de instancia es equivalente a un método "normal" de instancia con un bloque `synchronized(this) { ... }`. Y un método `synchronized` estático es equivalente a un método "normal" estático con un bloque `synchronized(A.class) { ... }` donde `A` es la clase que define el método estático.</sub>

Comment: El tema es más complicado de lo que parece a simple vista. Lo siguiente es incorrecto : "Mientras se ejecute un método synchronized de instancia llamado M, ningún otro hilo puede ejecutar: código que esté rodeado por un bloque synchronized(obj) { ... } donde obj es una referencia a la misma instancia a la que pertenece el método M."

Comment: Hola José. Es cierto que es un tema complicado. Por eso traté de ser muy cuidadoso con los términos que usé. ¿Puedes explicar lo que te parece incorrecto con esa sentencia?

Comment: He añadido a mi respuesta un ejemplo que contradice esa sentencia.

Comment: Jeje, de acuerdo. "rodeado" no era el término adecuado. Lo cambié por "protegido" ya que, como lo demostrastes, es posible "rodear" un código dentro de un bloque `synchronized` sin que ese código le pertenezca lógicamente a ese bloque.

Answer (score 3):

## SÍ, pueden acceder otros hilos.

Un hilo puede acceder a un Objeto con independencia de que otro hilo haya ejecutado un método `synchronized` de ese objeto.

El siguiente programa lo demuestra:

```
public class SynchronizedTest {
    static volatile boolean bloqueado = false;
    static final ObjetoBloqueado objBloqueado = new ObjetoBloqueado();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Crear un objeto Bloqueador.
        Bloqueador bloqueador = new Bloqueador();
        // Lanzarlo
        bloqueador.start();
        // Esperar a que el thread bloqueador haya llamado al 
        //método synchronized
        while( !bloqueado )
            Thread.yield();
        // Modificar el objeto bloqueado.
        objBloqueado.n = 20;
        // Imprimirlo para ver que si hemos podido modificarlo pese a estar
        //bloqueado
        System.out.println( objBloqueado.n );

        System.exit(0);
    }

    static class ObjetoBloqueado
    {
        public volatile int n;
        public synchronized void bloquea()
        {
            // Asignar un valor en el objeto bloqueado.
            n = 10;
            // Marcar que el objeto está bloqueado.
            SynchronizedTest.bloqueado = true;
            while(true)
                Thread.yield();
        }
    }

    static class Bloqueador extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            SynchronizedTest.objBloqueado.bloquea();
        }
    }
}
```

En este programa creamos un hilo de clase `Bloqueador` el cual llama al método `bloquea`, que es un método synchronized del objeto `Synchronized.objBloqueado`. Este método no termina nunca.

Mientras el thread principal espera a que se haya ejecutado este método `synchronized`. Y despues intenta acceder al objeto `SynchronizedTest.objBloqueado`, lo cual puede hacer sin problemas. ¡Incluso puede modificarlo!

Más aún. Mientras se ejecute un método synchronized de instancia llamado M, algún otro hilo **sí** puede ejecutar código que esté rodeado por un bloque synchronized(obj) { ... } donde obj es una referencia a la misma instancia a la que pertenece el método M.

El siguiente programa lo demuestra:

```
class SynchronizedTest 
{  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Compartido compartido = new Compartido();
        Aplicador ap;
        synchronized (compartido) {
            ap = new Aplicador() {
                public void func()
                {
                    compartido.logLlamada("func");
                }
            };
        }
        new Thread(() -> compartido.m1()).start();
        Thread.sleep(10);
        new Thread(() -> compartido.m2()).start();
        Thread.sleep(10);
        ap.func();
    }

    private static class Compartido {
        public synchronized void m1() {
            logLlamada("m1");
        }

        public synchronized void m2() {
            logLlamada("m2");
        }

        private void logLlamada(String methodName) {
            System.out.printf("%s - entrada%n", methodName);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.printf("%s - salida%n", methodName);
        }
    }

    public interface Aplicador {
        void func();
    }
}
```

El código de `func` está rodeado por un bloque `synchronized(compartido)` donde `compartido` es una referencia a la misma instancia a la que pertenecen los métodos `m1` y `m2`. Pese a eso func se puede ejecutar simultáneamente a `m1` y/o `m2`. La salida es :

```
m1 - entrada
func - entrada
m1 - salida
m2 - entrada
func - salida
m2 - salida
```

No basta con que el código esté rodeado por un bloque `synchronized`. Aún así puede haber dentro código, en el ejemplo anterior es código de una clase anónima definida dentro de ese bloque, que no está sometido al `synchronized` que le rodea.